# Is it correct/preferred to use "present" as adjective instead of "this" when writing legal stuff?

Tags: adjectives, word-usage, formality

Sometimes there are legal documents that, literally translated into English, contain the phrase "**the present document/contract**" whenever a reference to the document itself is made within the document.

Examples (formal/legal context):

1. **The present contract** describes 3 sections...
2. **This contract** describes 3 sections...

Questions (formal/legal context):

1. Is example #1 correct?
2. Which one is preferred?
3. Is there a better option like using "the current document" or hereby, hereon, etc.?

Comment: I think both are right.  Usually in contracts etc., the parties and the kind of contract, for the purpose of ease in subsequent part of it will be parenthetically phrased at the start of the document - conventionally - like, "the agreement to lease the property.....(description).... [here-in-after referred to as 'The Document'....].  Thereafter, it goes by using 'the document'. This can avoid repetitive use of 'the present document' or 'this document'.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer but 'the present contract' sounds to me like 'the contract currently in force' as opposed to 'the contract that will supercede it when we sign this document". I'm prepared to be told that I am wrong.